# How to count XML fields with non-zero value

Tags: sql, xml

Using SQL, I am trying to count the number of `<RepairOrder>` fields where the `<Total>` is not 0. From the below XML, I would want to return a count of 1.

```
<RepairOrders>
 <RepairOrder>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Total>50.00</Total>
 </RepairOrder>
 <RepairOrder>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Total>0</Total>
 </RepairOrder>
</RepairOrders>
```

I tried using this query:

```
ExternalData.value('count(/RepairOrders/RepairOrder)', 'int')
```

but it returned a count of 2 because it counted the 0 value field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ExternalData.value('count(/RepairOrders/RepairOrder[Total != 0])', 'int')
```

Comment: @EricCepress As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!